# Is there any way to count added line in a file per second in CentOS?

Tags: linux, file, count, centos

I have a file that fills in automatically when the server receives data from another server.

How can I calculate the number of lines added to this file per second?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, in pseudo code :

```
var lastNbLines = 0
do :
   var currentNbLines = cat file | wc -l # this is the correct command
   var diff = currentNbLines - lastNbLines
   echo diff #delta
   lastNbLines = currentNbLines
   sleep 1000 #in ms
While (true) // or other condition...
```

Translate this in bash ? :)